# How to calculate correct raster stats?

Tags: qgis, spatial-analysis

I've done a lot spatial analysis in ArcGIS. Then I decided to start to learn QGIS. I started with DEM analysis. But I found differences in statistics of DEM. ArcGIS correctly recognizes the lowest and maximum values (331 m, 2557 m), but QGIS does not. Based on statistics in QGIS the lowest value is 17 m greater (348 m) and the largest value 126 m greater than values in ArcGIS.

[image: DEM statistics in ArcGIS and QGIS]

I also see differenet values when adding DEM to the table of contents in QGIS. The lowest value is 398 m and the largest 2066 m. Can anybody help me how to calculate correct values?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stats in the Metadata are calculated in the same way as the Load Min/Max Values in the Style tab.  In my QGIS this defaults to an estimate of the Cumulative Count Cut (2%/98%).

To get the actual stats go to the Style tab, select the radio buttons next to "min/max" and "Actual (slower)" and then hit load.  This should update the statistics.

[image]